# show fields containing html tag in django templates like ordinary html tag

Tags: python, django

I have a model named news,news have a field named description,I use a RichTextArea to get the value of description from user,so user can enter html tags into this field,now I show the value of description in my template like this:

```
<div>
<h1>{{news.Title}}</h1>
{{news.Description}}
</div>
```

imagine that description field contain this text:

this is a test!

- item1
- item2
- item3

template show the value of description in the same way that is saved,I mean it shows tags in the template output not a formatted HTML!
what should I do?

Comment: Duplicate of too many questions to mention.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need the `safe` filter:

```
{{news.Description|safe}}
```